# How can I inherit data classes for repetitive codes in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, android-jetpack-compose, data-class

I wrote a composable function in kotlin compose. This composable function takes an ArrayList, in the same way, on another screen, there is an ArrayList that takes the same composable but a different data class.

What I want to do here is to have a composable to avoid code duplication because the codes are the same, only the type of the arraylist it receives is different as data class.

My composables are like this

**ItemsCategory composable**

```
@Composable
fun ItemsCategory(
    items: ArrayList<HealthCategoryDetailItems>
) {

    val boxQueryWidth = ScreenQuery(
        limits = arrayListOf(
            ScreenQueryLimit(
                max = 321,
                value = 135,
            ),
            ScreenQueryLimit(
                min = 321,
                max = 361,
                value = 160,
            )
        ),
        direction = ScreenDirection.HORIZONTAL,
        defaultValue = 170
    ).value().dp

    val itemsList = items.chunked(2)

    itemsList.forEach { listItem ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 15.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            listItem.forEach { item ->
                HealthItem(
                    width = boxQueryWidth,
                    imageSize = boxQueryWidth,
                    layoutPadding = 0.dp,
                    itemId = item.articleTypeId,
                    itemName = item.title ?: "",
                    image = item.image ?: "",
                    onClick = { itemId, itemName -> /* Handle onClick logic */ },
                    detailText = item.date,
                    detailTextColor = MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor,
                    shouldShowAdditionalImage = item.articleTypeId == 0,
                    additionalImg = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_home_content_recipe),
                    content = {}
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemsCategory VM**

```
private fun getHealthCategoryDetail(healthCategoryDetailRequestModel: HealthCategoryDetailRequestModel) {

        healthCategoryDetailUseCase.invoke(healthCategoryDetailRequestModel).onEach { result ->

            val data = result.data

            when (result) {

                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            response = data,
                            error = data?.isError == 1
                        )
                    }
                }
            ...
data class HealthCategoryDetailScreenState(
    val isLoading:Boolean = false,
    val error:Boolean = false,
    val response: HealthCategoryDetailResponseModel?=null
)
```

**TagDetailItem composable**

```
  @Composable
    fun TagDetailItem(
        items: ArrayList<HealthTagDetailItems>
    ) {
    
        val boxQueryWidth = ScreenQuery(
            limits = arrayListOf(
                ScreenQueryLimit(
                    max = 321,
                    value = 135,
                ),
                ScreenQueryLimit(
                    min = 321,
                    max = 361,
                    value = 160,
                )
            ),
            direction = ScreenDirection.HORIZONTAL,
            defaultValue = 170
        ).value().dp
    
        val itemsList = items.chunked(2)
    
        itemsList.forEach { listItem ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 15.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                listItem.forEach { item ->
                    HealthItem(
                        width = boxQueryWidth,
                        imageSize = boxQueryWidth,
                        layoutPadding = 0.dp,
                        itemId = item.articleTypeId,
                        itemName = item.title ?: "",
                        image = item.image ?: "",
                        onClick = { itemId, itemName -> /* Handle onClick logic */ },
                        detailText = item.date,
                        detailTextColor = MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor,
                        shouldShowAdditionalImage = item.articleTypeId == 0,
                        additionalImg = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_home_content_recipe),
                        content = {}
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**TagDetailItem VM**

```
 private fun getHealthCategoryDetail(healthTagDetailRequestModel: HealthContentDetailTagRequestModel) {

        tagDetailUseCase.invoke(healthTagDetailRequestModel).onEach { result ->

            val data = result.data

            when (result) {

                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = false,
                            response = data,
                            error = data?.isError == 1
                        )
                    }
                }
                 ...

data class HealthTagDetailScreenState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val error: Boolean = false,
    val response: HealthContentDetailTagResponseModel? = null
)
```

**Data classes**

**HealthTagDetailItems for TagDetailItem composable**

```
data class HealthContentDetailTagResponseModel(
    @SerializedName("is_error"    ) var isError     : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("data"        ) var data        : Data?   = Data(),
    @SerializedName("description" ) var description : String? = null
)


data class HealthTagDetailItems (
    @SerializedName("article_type_id" )  var articleTypeId : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("date"            )  var date          : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("image"           )  var image         : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id"              )  var id            : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("title"           )  var title         : String? = null
) 


data class Data (
    @SerializedName("article_type_name" ) var articleTypeName : String?          = null,
    @SerializedName("article_type_id"   ) var articleTypeId   : Int?             = null,
    @SerializedName("total_page"        ) var totalPage       : Int?             = null,
    @SerializedName("items"             ) var items           : ArrayList<HealthTagDetailItems> = arrayListOf()
)
```

**HealthCategoryDetailItems for ItemsCategory composable**

```
data class HealthCategoryDetailResponseModel(
    @SerializedName("is_error"    ) var isError     : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("data"        ) var data        : HealthCategoryDetailData?   = HealthCategoryDetailData(),
    @SerializedName("description" ) var description : String? = null
)

data class HealthCategoryDetailItems (
    @SerializedName("article_type_id" )  override var articleTypeId : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("date"            )  override var date          : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("image"           )  override var image         : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id"              )  override var id            : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("title"           )  override var title         : String? = null
)

data class HealthCategoryDetailData (
    @SerializedName("article_type_name" ) var articleTypeName : String?          = null,
    @SerializedName("article_type_id"   ) var articleTypeId   : Int?             = null,
    @SerializedName("total_page"        ) var totalPage       : Int?             = null,
    @SerializedName("items"             ) var items           : ArrayList<HealthCategoryDetailItems> = arrayListOf()
)
```

Comment: Data classes can't extend other classes, but they can implement interfaces.

Comment: I implement interface and I got this error  -> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface xxx.data.util.IContentItem. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.